# Mail Merge with formatting alters data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, csv, mail-merge

When I perform a mail merge with no formatting (the Merge Field being "MERGEFIELD  Cycle1Subject1StudentPercentage"), the answer that appears is correct "52.33"

However, if I do it using a formatting switch ( "MERGEFIELD  Cycle1Subject1StudentPercentage # 0") the answer is completely different "85"

I am stumped thus far. Is my CSV file incorrect? I have tried opening it, converting text to columns and then saving as CSV again

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us with some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, seems that I have answered my own question. My decimal character in language settings was set to a comma which was interfering. Setting it to a point corrected this.

Hope this helps someone